# Retrieve study, series, and image data from org.dcm4che2.data.DicomObject

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I'm trying to create my own PACS server using the open-source dcm4che2 toolkit. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the DICOM data in the format I need using the toolkit.

I've extended the org.dcm4che2.net.service.StorageService class and have overridden this method:

```
@Override
protected void onCStoreRQ(Association association, int pcid, DicomObject dicom, PDVInputStream dataStream, String tsuid, DicomObject response) throws IOException, DicomServiceException
{
    //use the DicomObject to get DICOM data
}
```

How can I retrieve study, series, and image data from  the org.dcm4che2.data.DicomObject object? I can't seem to find any documentation on how to leverage the toolkit to pull data from it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `DicomObject`, you can get the data many ways. You can iterate through the attributes using the `.datasetIterator()` method; you can `.get( Tag )` a specific `DicomElement`; or you could use a variety of the `.get***( Tag )` methods to get Strings, numbers, dates, etc.